# How to to toggle arrow from table header based on sorting?

Tags: reactjs, sorting, react-hooks

**Background:**

I am new to react, so pardon me if my query is very basic.

Query:

We have a requirement where we need to apply sorting on  columns. In this sorting one .net API is called and it will help to do sorting.
I managed to achieve sorting part but as per sorting column and sort order I need to add up or down arrow in table column.
To do that I saw conditional rendering react, did the changes accordingly in my table component but I am not able to get sortcolumn and sortorder from page to component.

Code:
Some part from table component:

```
    <Table bordered hover data-testid="task-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>
                <Form.Group>
                    <Form.Check id="selectAll" value={checkAll} onChange={selectAll}></Form.Check>
                </Form.Group>
              </th>
              {InboxColumns.map((colName, index) => (
                <th key={index} onClick={() =>  handleSorting(colName)}>{colName}
                <UpArrow/>
                <DownArrow/></th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          </tbody>
</Table>
```

**handlesorting function from page:**

```
function handleSorting(sortColumn: string): void {
    
    setOrder();
    sortDetails.column = sortColumn;
    const newEventLogRequest = eventLogRequest;
    newEventLogRequest.sortDetails = sortDetails;
    newEventLogRequest.page = 1;
    setPage(1);
    setEventLogRequest(newEventLogRequest);    
    dispatch(actions.getInboxes(eventLogRequest));    
    setEventList(inboxEvents);

    function setOrder() {
      if (sortDetails?.column === sortColumn && sortDetails?.order == SortOrder.ASC) {
        sortDetails.order = SortOrder.DESC;
      }
      else if (sortDetails?.column === sortColumn && sortDetails?.order == SortOrder.DESC) {
        sortDetails.order = SortOrder.ASC;
      }
      else {
        sortDetails.order = SortOrder.ASC;
      }
    }
  }
```

I want to toggle these uparrow , down arrow based on sort column, sort order.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional rendering for showing the up arrow and down arrow icons based on the `sortDetails` state. You can pass the `sortDetails` state to the table component and use it to decide which arrow to show.

Pass the `sortDetails` state to your table component:

```
<YourTableComponent sortDetails={sortDetails} />
```

Render the up arrow and down arrow icons based on the current `sortDetails`:

```
{InboxColumns.map((colName, index) => (
  <th key={index} onClick={() => handleSorting(colName)}>
    {colName}
    {sortDetails.column === colName && sortDetails.order === SortOrder.ASC && (
      <UpArrow />
    )}
    {sortDetails.column === colName && sortDetails.order === SortOrder.DESC && (
      <DownArrow />
    )}
  </th>
))}
```